# How to validate JSF Photo Upload with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, tomahawk

I am trying to validate JSF Photo Upload by jQuery validate but it does not work. 
form :

```
<h:form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <h:outputText for="file" value="Select Photo : " />
                    <t:inputFileUpload id="file1" name="file1" value="#{companyService.uploadedFile}" required="true" />
                    <h:message for="file" style="color: red;" />
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <h:commandButton value="Upload" styleClass="add" action="#{companyService.uploadPhoto}" />
                    <h:message for="uploadForm" infoStyle="color: green;" errorStyle="color: red;" />
                </tr>
                </table>
 </h:form>
```

script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$('textarea').elastic();
    $("#uploadForm").validate({
        rules: {
            file1: {
                required: true,
                accept: "jpg|gif|png|jpeg"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            file1: "jpg,gif,png,jpeg extensions are allowed"
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

I have imported jQuery libraries too...

Comment: How your validator can ever know what does mean file1